# How to say "she short changed me" (without negative conotation)?

Tags: translation, slang

For example, if I went to the bank to withdraw money from my account and my account showed I took out $50, but the bank teller only gave me $40. I don't want to imply the bank teller was trying to cheat me or had bad intentions, I just want to say that she "shorted" or "short-changed" me by $10.

Comment: Jipped has a negative connotation, meaning someone actively tried to rip you off.

Comment: Also, "jipped" (misspelling of [*gypped*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gyp#English)) is offensive because it is widely believed to have come from the word *Gypsy*. Be careful where you use it!

Comment: I am voting to close this question because the question is not related to this site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can say:

你少给了我10块钱。

Pinyin: nǐ shǎo gěi le wǒ shí kuài qián

Be sure to show the bank teller the money he/she gave you.

Answer (score 4):

I would use the following if I am shortchanged of $10:

你**少找**了十元（给我）。

And if I am given $10 extra change, I would use:

你**多找**了十元（给我）。

From 汉典, [找](http://www.zdic.net/z/1a/xs/627E.htm) means:

> (3) 退有余,把超过应收的钱物退还 [give change]。
>   如:找算(结算出多付而应找回的钱);找账(补足欠项);他找我一块钱

Comment: This would be not suitable in OP's situation. "超过 **应收的** 钱物" is the key point. OP's situation is "withdrawing money from an account": at that moment, the bank just gives you money but the action ***receiving your money*** hasn't happened. So I haven't heard Chinese people say so in this situation. Yes it's OK when you buy something, whatever but you should pay first, and the other side can 找 your money.

Comment: @Stan, yes, you are correct. In the context of the question, it does not apply. The reason is that the money received is not considered a change. I should read the question's context more carefully.

Answer (score 2):

Be polite to say:
`不好意思，还差10元`。

Answer (score 1):

Another polite way to go:

```
不好意思，這裡才四十。(Sorry, but here is only $40.)

bù hǎo yì sī，zhè lǐ cái sì shí。
```

which implies they should give you more.